# Triangles in spherical/elliptical geometry

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

In Euclidean geometry the sum of internal angles of a triangle is always $180^\circ$. In non-Eudlidean geometries it may be either less than this (in hyperbolic geometry) or more (spherical/elliptical geometry). Specifically in the latter the sum is always in between $180^\circ$ and $540^\circ$. However I wonder what is (in spherical or elliptical geometry) that prevent us from treating as triangle rather its outside than inside and concluding that the sum may be actually greater than $540^\circ$?

Comment: You could ask the same for usual Euclidean geometry.

Comment: The difference is that in the Euclidean space the complement of a triangle is unbounded.

Comment: A triangle is defined in Euclidean geometry as the intersection of three half-planes. I presume the non-euclidean definition is analogous, but I don't know enough about non-euclidean geometries to give an answer.

Comment: Well, this is the point I presume :). Since the complement of the intersection of three hemi-spheres is not an intersection of any three hemi-spheres (or at least I suppose it cannot be).